# iOS Facebook get friends list

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    m_allFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
    {
        if ([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions]indexOfObject:@"user_friends"] == NSNotFound)
        {

            [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_friends"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                                      [self getFBFriendListFunc];
                                                      NSLog(@"1");
                                                  }];

        }
        else
        {
            [self getFBFriendListFunc];
            NSLog(@"2");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_friends"]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                             if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                                 [self getFBFriendListFunc];
                                                 NSLog(@"3");
                                             }else{
                                                 NSLog(@"error");
                                             }
                                         }];
    }

}


-(void)getFBFriendListFunc
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@"me/friends result=%@",result);

                              NSLog(@"me/friends error = %@", error.description);

                              NSArray *friendList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

                              [m_allFriends addObjectsFromArray: friendList];
                          }];

}
```

I try to connect Facebook with their API, actually this code connect Facebook, Facebook ask me this application want to use your information than i confirmed. Last step, Facebook return again my application than this `getFBFriendListFunc` should be run but none of if/else work. Nothing display...

I get this codes on Facebook developer which code part wrong ? 
Any idea ?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this function on `AppDelegate.m` if this function does not exit login session never be work i hope this code help any one :)

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    return wasHandled;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For inviting users you can use the following code after adding the facebook-sdk

```
[FBWebDialogs
  presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:sharedFacebookHelper.session
  message:@"Your invite message"
  title:nil
  parameters:nil
  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                          } else {
                                              if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                  // User canceled.
                                                  NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                              } else {
                                                  // Handle the publish feed callback




                                                  } 

                                        }


}];
```